# Можно ли улучшить данный класс

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Имеется сей класс, для копирования `UTF8` массива символов в неуправляемую память подобно `char**`, все ли в нем нормально, и можно ли его улучшить?

```
public class IntPtrUtf8ArrayStr : IDisposable
{
    private bool isDispoed;

    public IntPtrUtf8ArrayStr(params string[] value)
    {
        int summarySize = 0;
        Length = value.Length;

        byte[][] tmpBytes = new byte[Length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            int countBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(value[i]) + 1;
            summarySize += countBytes;
            tmpBytes[i] = new byte[countBytes];
            Array.Copy(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value[i]), tmpBytes[i], countBytes - 1);
            tmpBytes[i][countBytes - 1] = (byte)'\0';
        }

    #if DEBUG
        Trace.WriteLine($"Summary bytes in array: {summarySize}", "INFO");
    #endif // ! DEBUG

        Pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(summarySize);

        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tmpBytes[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(Pointer, i * j, tmpBytes[i][j]);
            }
        }

        GC.KeepAlive(this);
    }

    public IntPtr Pointer { get; private set; }

    public int Length { get; private set; }

    ~IntPtrUtf8ArrayStr()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
    }

    private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return;
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer);
        Length = 0;
        Pointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        isDisposed = true;
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return;
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: Запутано как-то. Хорошо бы показать пример использования класса. Название IntPtrUtf8ArrayStr ни о чем не говорит, ArrayToPointer куда благозвучнее. Заявлено "для копирования UTF8 массива символов" а на вход идёт последовательность строк.

Comment: В чём необходимость использования этого класса? Хотелось бы увидеть наглядный пример Нужно отправить массив строк в библиотеку  С++? Отправьте так http://pastebin.ru/6ufYhYFj  http://pastebin.ru/38kOhsVb

Comment: Или массив строк превратить в IntPtr ? Тут как-то покомпактнее  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091618/how-can-i-copy-a-array-of-strings-into-an-unmanaged-char-double-pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Нужно использовать Метод Marshal.Copy (Byte[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32)
2. Ну и про использование рваных многомерных массивов https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2009/08/16/2313/